# How To Hide/Remove Additional Checkout Fields for Specific Products On Checkout Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, action, checkout

I have installed WooCommerce Checkout & Account Field Editor plugin on my WordPress website for adding additional fields to my checkout page. The purpose of installing this plugin is to add three additional fields like `how_you_heard_about_our_store`, `user_membership_level` and `user_refferer_name` to the checkout page for getting additional details from my users.

This is working fine and the user can provide the required information as needed during checkout. However, there is one product `Gift Certificate` that I need to exclude these additional fields on it when this product is on the checkout page.

The purpose is to hide these fields on this product only. I have 4 different variations of this product and I need these fields to be hidden for each of its variations.

I have tried my following techniques but this is actually for default WooCommerce fields.

https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/way-conditionally-show-hide-checkout-fields-specific-products-product-categories-store/

Also, I have tried the following as well with no luck:

```
    function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset($fields['order']["how_heard"]);
    unset($fields['order']["member_level"]);

    return $fields;
}
```

Is there any specific action or filter for removing additional fields from my checkout page? Any help would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'hide_checkout_fields' );

function hide_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
  foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $id = $product->get_id();
       $products = array(2516, 584, 2454);  // Product Ids

if (in_array($id, $products)) 
  { 
   unset($fields['order']['how_heard']);
   unset($fields['order']['member_level']);
  } 

  }
  return $fields; 
}
```